Differences between curly and square brace array declarations
With the introduction of collection expressions there are multiple ways in C# to declare an array with known elements:
Old Array Syntax with just Curly Braces
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Collection Expressions
int[] array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

It is also possible now to write empty arrays in different ways:
Empty Array - Curly Braces
int[] array = { };

Empty Array - Square Braces
int[] array = [];

Different ways to declare an array cause some confusion for me.
I would like to know if there are differences between these declarations?
Is there any benefit of using one over there other in some scenarios?
Are there performance benefits that would advocate the usage of one declaration over the other (even if it is for some very specific scenarios)?
UPDATE
Removed part of the array declaration approaches to make the question less similar to other question to avoid duplicate confusion.

They are all the same except one. The only difference is that the empty [] can be a singleton and not a new array.

I don't understand why my question is considered a duplicate. The other question doesn't mention new collection expression at all. I have edited my question for it to be more focused on the differences between collection expression and old array declarations.

Okay. I have added another duplicate target.

@Sweeper there is a actually a part in my question about empty arrays which is not present in the other question. But if you are insisting on marking my question as duplicate then so be it.

To answer it short and easy. Besides readability...no... performance won't be affected. You could use the old way if you need an empty array since that makes it in my opinion a lot cleaner to read but that kind of goes against the principle of an array since they are not dynamic.
Tl;Dr; No
Edit: As mentioned by @Oliver Jacot-Descombes the [] way of declaring an empty array accepts Array.Empty<T>(); the curly bracket style does not and will create a new empty array every time

Except that [] will take Array.Empty<T>(). This will return the same instance for the same T.

True that I forgot about the singleton handling. I will edit my answer.
